# How to Remove Specialized OSBB Aluminum Inner Shell

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have a 2014 Specialized Tarmac that uses press-in aluminum inner shell cups to hold the bottom bracket BB30 bearings.  These cups are affixed to the carbon frame with 2 part epoxy.  (see page 2 of this tech guide:  https://media.specialized.com/support/0000003319/0000003319_IG0338_revC.pdf).  I would like to replace the cups.  How can they be removed without damaging the carbon fiber frame?  (for a picture of the shells, go to page 3 of this link, and view the 2014 alum. inner shell to the 2014 SBC Road Frame:  https://praxiscycles.com/wp-content/uploads/PRAXIS-FRAME-GUIDE.pdf)

Comment: From the bottom of page 2: "To remove the cups from the frame, pull the bearings out as shown on page 5, then lightly tap the backside of the cups in a circular pattern with a large flat surface. Do not use a screwdriver, as it may damage the cups."

You may want to let your shop do this, given the other tools required unless you have them for some reason.

Comment: Batman, where did you find the quoted language?

Comment: Its footnote 9 on page 2 of the specialized tech guide.

Answer (score 1):

I have a carbon framed bike with a press fit BB. Recently the non-drive side bearing disintegrated, and having the [Park tool to remove/install the cups](http://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-set-for-bb30-pf30-bbt-30-3) I thought I'd be good to go.

The drive side cups popped out no problem, but the non-drive one had frozen solid in the way that aluminium seatposts can in carbon frames. Despite hammering it like all bezoomny, to the point where bits of metal were breaking off the inside of the shell where the tool rests against, it would not budge.

In the end I got a dremel and very very carefully cut through the remaining bearing shell and then the BB cup, and it still took some pretty good whacks with a hammer against a wooden drift for it to finally give up.

So, get the right tool, or take it to an LBS/mechanic who does. Its surprising how easy the cups can pop out when done properly. Failing that, and as a total last resort, you can cut them out with a steady hand.